# Libre Office crashed but not closed. Will I lose unsaved changes?

Tags: windows-7, crash, libreoffice

Libre Office crashed. Will I lose unsaved changes.

I was doing my thing on the computer.. I tried pasting some pic into mspaint, rotating it, went back into mspaint.. maybe tried a paste.Suddenly a few programs crashed.  What happened on screen looked a bit like as if i'd clicked in the bottom right it looked like things were suddenly either closing or minimising..but it wasn't that as not all programs closed. So it looked as if maybe i'd issued some shortcut to shut windows but I hadn't as notepads didn't attempt to close.

This error came up for a little program called KeePass

[image]

Libre Writer gave an error too

Every single LibreWriter window I have open. Whether Libre Calc  or Libre Writer

[image]

I get that

[image]

I don't want to lose any unsaved data.

Other programs are fine. Notepad windows are fine.  Gvim is fine.  Microsoft Excel is fine. Even Firefox and Chrome are fine!  I've closed some programs.

I haven't used Libre Writer that much. It looks not very reliable to me, but anyhow.

The text of my documents are showing but I can't scroll and it's just showing as greyed out

[image]

What can I do here?

I don't know if it autosaves by default

Note- I will post an answer why I think the answer is no, though there are still some unsolved things.

**Added**

This directory which some webpages suggested would store a backup if there is one, ´C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\backup>´ was empty when the message came up about libre office wanting to close. Then I clicked "debug" then "cancel". And libre office closed. I checked that directory and still no files there.

This is the state of tools..options..

[image]

And that's the default.

Comment: this directory `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\backup>` is empty .. i am not sure if it will fill when/if i click "close" to libre writer's crash.

Comment: I clicked debug then it offered me some choices and i clicked cancel and it closed. The directory is still empty

Comment: I opened libre writer and it listed files offering to recover. I said yes. How recent the recovery is I don't know. Not too bad but it's very questionable.. When did it last autosave and did the autosave go to the main file or to a temp file and if a temp file then where

Comment: LibreOffice has a setting in *Options>Load/Save>General* for the AutoRecovery save frequency. You will have lost no more work time than you've set there.  See https://hetmanrecovery.com/recovery_news/how-to-recover-a-document-libreoffice.htm for recovery info. As for blaming LibreOffice, you clearly state the system crashed when using MS Paint! BTW, do not add comments to your own question; **edit the question**, instead.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  I can add comments to my question and decide how and if they are to be incorporated. Sometimes a comment is more relevant to an answer than to a question. I will deal with comments when i'm ready, when I have more information and ideas on where and how to incorporate them.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have now had some time to incorporate comments into the question.. The statement you made "As for blaming LibreOffice, you clearly state the system crashed when using MS Paint! ".   That is absurd.  There isn't much to say to something that absurd.  Do you even understand that Libre Office crashed?  It's not "the system " that crashed. And MsPaint didn't crash.

Comment: Based on the picture of the `Options - Load/Save`, it seems that auto save was (is?) not set. So, the files were not saved automatically.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yeah I think Mokubai messed up my question by taking the answer I posted and sticking it into the question(which lowers the quality of the question). That screenshot was originally from the answer I posted. By the way Libre Office did claim to have "recovered" the files. I prefer a good quality question and some answers that are a a bit low quality and could improve in future, than a lower quality question.

Answer (score -1):

I think it'd lose unsaved changes.

In order to be sure, the ideal thing would be if I could simulate a crash, so as to test the behaviour but that aside.

Fortunately in my case I guess I must have instinctively done ctrl-s after my last edit to the word document I was concerned about, or i'd not written much in it  since  it doesn't look old to me judging by the content.  And I think I might have lost some data from a spreadsheet document but there wasn't much there.

My recent test , writing text and waiting, indicates that maybe there isn't any autosave  going on.

The odt files that were open have times of

```
16/01/2023  15:51
03/01/2023  01:15
03/01/2023  19:12
```

The crash was around when I posted the question, so 16/01/2023 at around 21:00

When I reopened Libre Office it spoke about recovery of files but the files have the same date and time stamps as hours or days before the crash.  So maybe "recovery" was just for show. And if it did anything eg without saving back to the file, then i'd ask where did it store any temporary files in.

I think maybe I must have done ctrl-s on any important documents hours before the crash. But I can't see any way to track anything to be sure

After I let Libre Office close, I opened it and it claimed to recover files. But I think that's maybe that's just for show in this case. It was after it closed that I was able to bring up tools..options . And that  tools..options screenshot shows nothing for backup and nothing for "save autorecovery information".